# OAuth-Google Latitude integration in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, oauth, google-latitude

Has anyone integrated with Google Latitude (or any Google API, for that matter) with Clojure and can point me to a working example? I'm trying authenticate to the Google Latitude API and running into all sorts of problems, for example a "Token Invalid" error from Google- nothing else- after logging in for the User Approval URI.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up making a few tweaks to make clj-oauth compatible with the Latitude API (for example, Google OAuth requires a :scope parameter that wasn't supported in the original version of clj-oauth). Until my changes get merged into the official version, those of you who are interested can check out my branch [here](http://github.com/yayitswei/clj-oauth).

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [clj-oauth](http://github.com/mattrepl/clj-oauth) and the provided examples? Granted, they are for Twitter, but I doubt that Google Latitude's OAuth will be very different...